# Proof that e is the following infinite fraction:

Tags: continued-fractions

How do I show

$e = 2+ 1/(1+1/(1+4+1/(1+...$?

Where for every 2ones in a row there is an even number (I am sure you all know what I am talking about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following paper by Henry Cohn:

[A short proof of the simple continued fraction expansion of e](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601660)

Abstract: This note presents an especially short and direct variant of Hermite's proof of the simple continued fraction expansion $e = [2,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,\dots]$ and explains some of the motivation behind it.

Take also a look through the references, especially ["The simple continued fraction expansion of $e$"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318113?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by C. D. Olds.

Comment: ...which is actually the first result that comes up (after MathWorld) when googling "continued fraction e".